# Python loop files from a specific filename

Tags: python-3.x, file, loops

For example:

Under the folder, the file list is like:

```
20110101  
20110102  
20110103  
...  
20140101  
20140102   
...  
20171231
```

How can I start looping those files not from the natural beginning (20110101)
but from a middle one (20140101)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can get an **unsorted** list of all the files in the current directory with `os.listdir()`. So you need to first sort this alphabetically (the default when using the `sorted()` function), and find the index of that "beginning file" and iterate from there.

So, in code, the above would look something like:

```
import os
b = '20110101'
fs = sorted(os.listdir())
for f in fs[fs.index(b):]:
    ...
```